# Como que faz um botão redirecionar para uma pagina após ter o email e senha confirmado?

Tags: javascript

Como que faço para ser direcionado a uma proxima pagina após ser confirmado o "email" e "senha" no JavaScript

```
<button onclick="b_login()" id="botaoLogin">LOGIN</button>

<script>
function b_login(){
  var email = login_email.value;
  var senha = login_senha.value;
  var email_passou = (email == 'christian@gmail.com')
  var senha_passou = (senha == '1234');
  if(email_passou && senha_passou){
    alert('Aguarde');
  }
  else{
    if(!email_passou){
       alert("Email invalido");
    }
    if(!senha_passou){
        alert("Senha invalida");
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simulando um clique do mouse:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

Simulando um redirecionamento HTTP:

```
window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
```

No seu caso, seria algo assim:

```
if(email_passou && senha_passou){
   window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
}
```